# The matched days count between two dates ranges

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two dates for reservation for example I have reservation starts at 2020-03-01 
and ends at 2020-04-10.

So when I make select query to know how many days this room has been reserved in the 4th month i want to get count of days 10

Is there anyway to do it in Mysql.

```
SELECT from_date , to_date  
FROM reservations 
WHERE room_id = ? 
AND from_date >= "2020-04-01" AND to_date >= "2020-04-30"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `datediff() and`least()`and`greatest()`.  I think the logic you want is:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(LEAST(to_date, '2020-04-30'),
                GREATEST(from_date, '2020-04-01')
               ) + 1  
FROM reservations 
WHERE room_id = ? AND
      to_date >= '2020-04-01' AND
      from_date <= '2020-04-30';
```

Note that the date logic in the `WHERE` clause has been modified.  This is the correct logic for determining if two time periods overlap.  The first ends after the second starts; the first starts before the second ends.